# How to print tiff files automatically?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a folder which will contain only one tiff file at a time, so the moment I receive one I should be able to print it to the default printer.  I have a small Windows application which is looking for any tiff files in the particular folder.  I just have to print it to the default printer the moment a tiff file is received.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this using C#?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PritinginCSharp11222005040630AM/PritinginCSharp.aspx here is a good link to look at too http://www.bobpowell.net/generating_multipage_tiffs.htm

Comment: install a virtual Tiff Printer http://www.zan1011.com/

Answer (score 6):

As OP said [in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1233466/revisions), this can be done with this piece of code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process printProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
printProcess.StartInfo.FileName = strFileName;
printProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
printProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
printProcess.Start();
```